# Infinite digest loop inside custom filter of angularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am displaying a list of tables and each row is also expandable. I want to filter the list using the property of expandable table. For example if the main table show the general info of student and expandable table shows the marks of subject for that student. I want to filter the complete table by marks column. So the filtering should display the parent table with matched marks.

```
var students = [{ 
   name: "neha",
   address: "abc"
   marks: [{
      subject: "english",
      marks: 80
   }, {
      subject: "hindi",
      marks: 60
   }]
 }, { 
   name: "sneha",
   address: "xyz"
   marks: [{
      subject: "english",
      marks: 70
   }, {
      subject: "math",
      marks: 50
   }]
 }
```

For this
I am using custom filter to filter the list. Inside custom filter I am using "filterFilter" to filter the marks array.

filterBy is the property which keeps track of property against which the value will be tested.

For example the values can be 
1) filterBy = {property: "marks.subject", value: "hindi"} //filter on nested table

2) filterBy = {property: "name": value: "neha"} //filter on parent table

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.filter("filterTable", function(filterFilter) {

    return function(list, filterBy) {
        var filteredList = [],
            len,
            i,
            j,
            property,
            present,
            tempList,
            listCopy,
            properties = [];

        //creating a copy as filter will update the list and rest filter will not work properly
        listCopy = angular.copy(list);
        len = listCopy.length;

        if(filterBy.value) {

            properties = filterBy.property.split(".");

            //if filter on nested table
            if(properties.length > 1) {
                property = properties[1];

                for ( i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    tempList = {};
                    //using filterFilter defined by angularjs
                    listCopy[i].disks = filterFilter(list[i].disks, { [property] : filterBy.value });
                    console.log(list[i].disks);
                    if(listCopy[i].disks.length) {
                        filteredList.push(listCopy[i]);
                    }  

                }
            } else {
                property = filterBy.property;

                for ( i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                    if(list[i][property].indexOf(filterBy.value) > 0) {
                        filteredList.push(list[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            return filteredList;
        } else {
            return list;
        }
    };
});
```

But this is going into infinite digest cycle. I have spent a long time on this and still not able to resolve. Please help me with it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are `deep copy` array.

Angular's ngRepeat doesn't realize that those objects are equal because ngRepeat tracks them by identity. New object leads to new identity. This makes Angular think that something has changed since the last check, which means that Angular should run another check (aka digest).

Try update logic of filter without `angular.copy()`

Update:

Instead of `angular.copy` use `flat copy`:

`var newArray= oldArray.slice();` // clones the array and returns the reference to the new array.

Comment: If I am using without angular.copy, then its modifying the list. Because of this the next filter operation will not work correctly as the list is updated it is working on the updated list as the value is copied by reference

Comment: Updated answer, try `flat copy` of array

Comment: If I am just copying it flat, it still update the list and the filter operation thereafter affects the result. Can you please provide one filddle for the same.